# What does first and second approximations mean in this context?

Tags: calculus-of-variations

In the [Feynman lectures on physics](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_19.html), Feynman in talking about the principle of least action, discusses how we should be able to find the true path $x(t)$ which has the least action, and the way to do it he says:

> When we
>   have a quantity which has a minimum—for instance, in an ordinary
>   function like the temperature—one of the properties of the minimum is
>   that if we go away from the minimum in the first order, the deviation
>   of the function from its minimum value is only second order. At any
>   place else on the curve, if we move a small distance the value of the
>   function changes also in the first order. But at a minimum, a tiny
>   motion away makes, in the first approximation, no difference (Fig.
>   19–8).
>
> “That is what we are going to use to calculate the true
>   path. If we have the true path, a curve which differs only a little
>   bit from it will, in the first approximation, make no difference in
>   the action. Any difference will be in the second approximation, if we
>   really have a minimum.

The thing I understand from the diagram is that, near the minimum region the curve can be approximated as a parabola. Anywhere else on the curve, a tiny segment can be modeled as a straight line.

I do not understand what he means by *first* and *second* approximations, and that in the first approximation there is no difference, but there is a difference in the second approximation.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Any smooth function can be approximated by a polynomial in a small interval.

$$f(x)\approx a+bx+cx^2+dx^3+\cdots$$

For very small $x$, only the first term matters and the function can be seen as a constant

$$f(x)\approx a.$$
This is called the zero-th order approximation. It expresses the local value of the function.

For a little larger $x$, you must take into account the first term, and that yields a first order, linear approximation

$$f(x)\approx a+bx.$$

It expresses the local slope of the function.

A yet better approximation is obtained by adding more terms, yielding a second  order, parabolic approximation.

$$f(x)\approx a+bx+cx^2.$$

It expresses the local concavity of the function.

The approximation coefficients can be estimated by taking the derivatives at $0$ [or another value that you like] and identifying:

$$f(x)=a+bx+cx^2+dx^3\cdots,f(0)=a$$
$$f'(x)=b+2cx+3dx^2\cdots,f'(0)=b$$
$$f''(x)=2c+3dx\cdots,f''(0)=2c.$$

Now in the case of an extremum, we have $f'(0)=b=0$, so that there is no first order approximation and one needs to jump to the second order.

$$f(x)\approx a\to f(x)\approx a+cx^2.$$

Here are constant (green), linear (red) and parabolic (black) approximations of the exponential and hyperbolic cosine functions.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I was reading your answer and I found it very helpful. I have a similar question http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2087861/333392 which has been troubling a lot. Perhaps the concept is not that clear. Could you please also answer that. It would be a great help. Thank you !

Comment: @Shashaank: sorry, I don't answer "on demand" (and I don't like to read questions that shout a lot).

Comment: Ok that's great ! By the way I wasn't demanding. I was just asking because I liked this answer and thought that if you could explain that answer as well , I would get it and it would be great help. And I was not shouting the question , I was just requesting. I hope that's the point of stack exchange that people can learn and if you feel I was wrong or rude then sorry !

Comment: I didn't want to hurt you, sorry. But on web pages bold font is shouting.

Comment: No no it's not that.  I did not know that bold font is shouting , I reckon stack exchange went wrong. I always thought that I could bold the font to be more precise in the points in which I had doubt. That's why I used bold. I won't now. Nevertheless its ok if you don't wish to answer , it's your wish. Sorry !

Comment: @Shashaank Italics are much softer (IMO).

Comment: ok next time I will write in italics.....I just thought that bold will signify the doubt properly. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

What he means is that if we take some path $p$ and a variation $V$, and make another variation that we can choose to be small by parameterizing it as $\epsilon V$, then we can ask the questions (for each $n$):

What is $$ \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{A[p+\epsilon V] - A[p]}{\epsilon^n} ?$$

If this expression is non-zero for $n=1$ then we say that the deviation is first order.  If it is zero for $n = 1$ but non-zero for $n=2$ then the deviation is second order.  When Feynman says "only second order" he means "not first order"; that is, the deviation could be third or higher order as well as second order.

There is a real subtlety for the mathematical purist, concerning the choice of allowed "test" variations $\{V\}$.

At any rate "zero in first approximation" means that that limit is zero when $n=1$.  If it looks like the familiar definition of a derivative, conceptually they are closely related, but here we mean to say that the limit is zero for all (suitable) test variations $V$.